# Classify sequence of flags

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, classification, deep-neural-networks

I am not able to find an answer to how I should classify a varying number of sequence of binary flags + other features. My data looks like this (these are events, so the order is important and I may have other features in addition to sequence):

| ID | Flag 1 | Flag 2 | Flag 3 | Other Feature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.1 |
| A | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.3 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3.1 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1.1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.0 |

Notice that ID:B does not have the same number of entries (only 2). Any suggestion on how I should organize this data and what should I use to classify? How do I better capture the sequence of Flags? During inference, I will provide the sequence of flags [[1,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]] OR [[0,1,0],[1,1,0]] and "other feature" to get the label since the order of sequence makes up the positive or negative label.

Comment: Can you please put your **specific question** in the title? Thanks. "Classify sequence of flags" is not really a question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a *classification* problem over a *time-series*, basically. You need to group all the events with the same ID under a single sequence, like `[A, A, A]` (is one sample) and `[B,B]` (is another).

Your *targets* ($y$) will be the class label, for each sequence and each element of the sequence. Then the $x$ will comprise the three flags and "other feature(s)" you have.

You can tackle the problem with three kinds of neural networks: **1D CNNs** (convolutional nets), **RNNs** (recurrent nets), and even **transformers** (i.e. attention-based models).

- Since you have sequences of the kind $(B,T,N)$ - where $B$ is the batch size, $T$ the num of events with same ID (you may need to zero-pad), and $N$ the number of features - and have a target for each $t\in T$, you need to predict the class label for each timestep $T$, and each sequence in $B$.
- So you're output won't be a single value for one input sequence but a sequence of values of size $T$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - much appreciated. So, let me elaborate this a bit. If I take data as a sequence and because I don't know the number of entries ahead of time, I will always zero pad and truncate to get a fixed length of sequence (for the above example, sample "A" would look like: [1,1,0,0.1,   0,1,0,0.3,   0,0,1,3.1] and "B" would look like: [1,1,0,0.1,   0,1,0,0.3,   0,0,0,0.0]). Is this correct? In that case, I can also use something simple like XGBoost etc.?

Comment: You can do that, but I was thinking about representing `A` as `[[1, 1, 0, 0.1], [0, 1, 0, 0.3], [0,0,1,3.1]]` so as a `(1,3, 4)` tensor, and `B` (with zero-pad) as `[[1,1,0,0.1], [0,1,0,0.3], [0,0,0,0.0]]`. You transform your dataset accordingly, then train a RNN by sampling $N$ of such sequences to build a mini-batch, and repeat that until convergence. Actually, if you provide `masks` to the RNN is as if having varying-length sequences. For example, the mask for `B` should be `1,1,0`. To not consider the last timestep.